# PHP PDO Query returning bool(false)

Tags: php, pdo, insert

I'm new to PDO and was trying to make a register and log-in.  This is returning bool(false)
when I tried to debug it.  Can't find out why it's happening.

```
<?php
       include_once('db.php');

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = sha1($_POST['password']);
    $confirm_password = sha1($_POST['confirm_password']);
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $fetchUsers = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'");

        if(!empty($username) &&
           !empty($email) &&
           !empty($password) &&
           !empty($confirm_password) &&
           filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) &&
           $password == $confirm_password &&
           $fetchUsers->fetchAll() != $username) {

                $insertSQL = "INSERT INTO `users`
                             (`username`, `email`, `password`, `ip`) VALUES
                             (:username => '$username', :email => '$email', :password => '$password', :ip => '$ip')";

                    $insertUser = $db->query($insertSQL);
                        var_dump($insertUser);

                echo '<br /><br />You have successfully registered.';


           }

           else {

                echo '<br /><br />There was an error with your registration.';

          }


?>
```

Comment: Word of advice, let PDO throw exceptions on errors; `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`.

Comment: Also, use a password hash like `bcrypt` instead of `sha1()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `INSERT` query is wrong. Also use `prepare` for prepared statement.

```
$insertSQL = "INSERT INTO `users` (`username`, `email`, `password`, `ip`) 
VALUES (:username,:email,:password,:ip)";

$insertUser = $db->prepare($insertSQL);
$insertUser->execute(array(':username' => $username, ':email' => $email, ':password' => $password, ':ip' => $ip));
```

Comment: Looks like that wasn't the issue.  Check the below answer.

Comment: @user2555621 Do you think your `INSERT` statement is valid?

Comment: Yes.  As stated above it looks like an issue with something else.

Edit: Nevermind.  Looks like an issue with the query too.  I removed the username check part and it's still not inserting into the database.  I edited my code and it's using what you put.

Comment: @user2555621 see this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

Comment: @user2555621 The other answer addresses the first issue, but once that is resolved, you will find that your `INSERT ..` will also fail, so this answer is also correct.

Comment: I already completely understand MySQL.  I'm making a mistake, that doesn't mean I need to read over documents...  I'm new to PDO, not to MySQL.

Comment: @user2555621: Really? Because the query you wrote has nothing to do with PDO (maybe it got you confused) but the query itself is MySQL.

Comment: Using mysql_query I've never used colons.  I've always put my variables ( values ) in strings.  It's new to me hence why I'm having problems.  Doesn't mean I need to read over docs.  I updated my code to Yogesh's and it's still not working.  So it isn't my INSERT query or what?

Comment: @user2555621 Which query return bool?

Comment: When I do a var_dump($insertUser) it returns this: http://puu.sh/3AWqQ.png  Using your code.

Comment: @user2555621: [Let us continue this conversation in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php)

Comment: @user2555621 That doesn't mean it returns bool.

Comment: Yes, but it's still not inserting into the DB...

Answer (score 0):

In the If condition the code `$fetchUsers->fetchAll() != $username` is seems that not correct.
As `fetchAll` will return the array and you are comparing it with string.

so remove the `$fetchUsers->fetchAll() != $username` code from the if condition. and then check. May be it will work.

Comment: Okay, I'll do that.  But how can I make it check if the username is already taken.  I know in MySQL I'd just use mysql_fetch_array and then the variable of my array with a ['username'].  How can I do this in PDO?

Comment: what you think by this code you can check? you can use the `num_rows` if it will return the 1 or more than that then user is taken and if it returns 0 then the user name not taken.

Comment: So if($fetchUsers->fetchColumn() == 1)?  Something like that?

Comment: @user2555621 right but this will be`if ($fetchUsers->fetchColumn() == 0)` if this will be 1 then user is exist.